# How to average out values for same key in Python dict

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I have the following list of dictionaries in Python.

```
[{"country": "IE", "values": ["Server1-17.6650", "Server3-78.6064", "Server2-3.7286"]}, {"country": "CA", "values": ["Server1-100.0000"]}, {"country": "DE", "values": ["Server2-100.0000"]}, {"country": "JP", "values": ["Server2-100.0000"]}, {"country": "IT", "values": ["Server1-100.0000"]}, {"country": "US", "values": ["Server1-6.3158", "Server3-15.7895", "Server2-77.8947", "Server1-5.5556", "Server3-2.7778", "Server2-91.6667", "Server1-12.6145", "Server3-86.8043", "Server2-0.5811"]}, {"country": "CZ", "values": ["Server1-100.0000"]}, {"country": None, "values": ["Server1-100.0000", "Server2-100.0000", "Server2-100.0000", "Server1-100.0000"]}, {"country": "A", "values": ["Server2-100.0000"]}, {"country": "IL", "values": ["Server1-100.0000"]}, {"country": "BR", "values": ["Server2-100.0000"]}, {"country": "KP", "values": ["Server1-100.0000"]}, {"country": "SG", "values": ["Server1-79.2000", "Server2-20.8000"]}, {"country": "ES", "values": ["Server1-100.0000"]}]
```

Now for each of the `values` if the server name repeats in the list I have to average out it's values after the `-` for the server. Essentially for the above list the final output becomes.

```
[{"country": "IE", "values": ["Server1-17.6650", "Server3-78.6064", "Server2-3.7286"]}, {"country": "CA", "values": ["Server1-100.0000"]}, {"country": "DE", "values": ["Server2-100.0000"]}, {"country": "JP", "values": ["Server2-100.0000"]}, {"country": "IT", "values": ["Server1-100.0000"]}, {"country": "US", "values": ["Server1-8.1619", "Server3-35.1238", "Server2-56.7141"]}, {"country": "CZ", "values": ["Server1-100.0000"]}, {"country": None, "values": ["Server1-100.0000", "Server2-100.0000", "Server2-100.0000", "Server1-100.0000"]}, {"country": "AU", "values": ["Server2-100.0000"]}, {"country": "IL", "values": ["Server1-100.0000"]}, {"country": "BR", "values": ["Server2-100.0000"]}, {"country": "KP", "values": ["Server1-100.0000"]}, {"country": "SG", "values": ["Server1-79.2000", "Server2-20.8000"]}, {"country": "ES", "values": ["Server1-100.0000"]}]
```

I tried the following code in Python

```
for key_dict in resp:
    for i, value in enumerate(key_dict['values']):
        for j, new_value in enumerate(key_dict['values']):
            if value[:value.index('-')] == new_value[:new_value.index('-')]:
                key_dict['values'][i] = value[:value.index('-')] + str(float(value[value.index('-'):]) + float(new_value[new_value.index('-'):]))
                del key_dict['values'][j]
```

But that does not produce the result I need. Can someone point out how to do this in python.

Comment: Do you have control over the data structure? It would make way more sense to make the 'values' be a dictionary with server names and their resulting values.

Comment: Did you downvote all 3 answers, or did someone else just come by and do that for no reason? Because I could maybe understand someone legitimately downvoting mescalinum's (it has no explanation, and it's effectively just an obfuscated way of doing the last version in my answer), but I can't imagine why anyone would downvote ohruunuruus's.

Comment: No I did not down vote any of these answers here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of those problems that's trivial with the right data structure, and painful without. If `values` were a dictionary mapping server names to lists of numbers, instead of a big list of strings, this would be easy:

If you can control how the values arrive in the first place, you should do so. If you can't, you may want to convert them manually. Like this:

```
for key_dict in resp:
    new_values = {}
    for value in key_dict['values']:
        name, number = value.split('-', 1)
        new_values.setdefault(name, []).append(float(number))
    key_dict['values'] = new_values
```

And now, averaging them is trivial:

```
for key_dict in resp:
    averages = {}
    for name, numbers in key_dict['values'].items():
        averages[name] = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
    key_dict['values'] = averages
```

If you really need to turn it back into a string at the end, you can:

```
for key_dict in resp:
    key_dict['values'] = ['{}-{}'.format(name, value) 
                          for name, value in key_dict['values'].items()]
```

Of course you can put this all together inline if you really want to:

```
for key_dict in resp:
    values = {}
    for value in key_dict['values']:
        name, number = value.split('-', 1)
        values.setdefault(name, []).append(float(number))
    values = ['{}-{}'.format(name, sum(numbers)/len(numbers))
              for name, numbers in values.items()]
    key_dict['values'] = values
```

Comment: Can you help me if instead of `len(numbers)` if I want to divide by max length of lists so my value actually adds unto 100 . The above solution results in a split that adds up to more than a 100.

Comment: @user567797: To get the max length of lists in a dict `d`, `max(d.values(), key=len)` will return the list with the longest length, then `len(that)` will give you the length of that list. Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: @user567797: OK, if you want to _sum_ the lengths of all of the lists, you use the `sum` function instead of the `max` function: `sum(len(v) for v in d.values())`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `groupby` here:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import groupby

def average_servers(server_list):

    post_split = [x.split('-') for x in server_list]
    averages = []

    for server, data in groupby(sorted(post_split), lambda x: x[0]):

         cur_average = np.mean([float(x[1]) for x in list(data)])
         averages.append('{}-{}'.format(server, cur_average))

    return averages
```

Then apply the function to generate a new list of strings to serve as the value for the `values` key:

```
for entry in your_data_structure:
    entry['values'] = average_servers(entry['values'])
```

Comment: Someone downvoted all 3 answers a couple minutes ago, with no explanation. No idea why.